# Как сверстать такую обводку?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так:

```css
.text p{
        position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #fde428;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
border-bottom: 2px solid #fde428;

}

.text{
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
 width: 50%;
 
  
}
.text h2{
position: relative;

}
.text::after{
    content: "";
    width: 180px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 5px solid #fde428;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: transparent;

    top: -20px;
right: calc(50px - 180px);
}
.text h2::after{

         content: "";
        width: 5px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #fde428;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: transparent;
top: -17px;
right: 50px;

}
.text p::after{
     content: "";
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 5px;
    height: 16px;
    
       cursor: default; background:#fde428;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: transparent;
    top: -22px;
    right: 50%;
}
.text p:before{
        text-decoration: none;
     content: "";
    width: 5px;
    height: 54px;
     cursor: default;  background:#fde428;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: transparent;
    top: 22px;
    right: 50%;
}
```

```html
          <div class="text">
                
                    <h2>Consumer<br>Products<br>Consulting</h2>
                    <p >LEARN MORE</p>
                  
                </div>
```

Да уж больно криво и костыльно мне кажется.

Comment: А где шаблон взяли если не секрет?

Comment: https://howdyho.net/?category=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить такое решение на [codePen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYbZKe?editors=1100).

```
body {
  background-color: #555;
}
.text{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
  width: 180px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 5px solid #fde428;
  border-left: transparent;
}
.text::before,
.text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
}
.text::before {
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 125px 0 #fde428;
}
.text::after {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 #fde428,
          5px 180px 0 #fde428;
}
.text h2{
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-60%);
}
.text p{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fde428;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fde428;
}
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, но в IE и Edge проверяли? Свойство `box-shadow` отображается размыто, выглядит не очень красиво)

Answer (score 3):

Если бы не промежуточный бордер все было бы совсем красиво. А так пока промежуточный вариант, может кто поправит...

```css
body {
   display: flex;
   min-height: 100vh;
   background-color: darkblue;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   --bordersize: 8px;
}
fieldset {
   margin: auto;
   min-width: 8em;
   min-height: 6em;
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   border: var(--bordersize) solid yellow;
}
legend {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   color: white;
   font-size: 160%;
   text-align: right;
}
legend a {
   color: yellow;
   font-size: 50%;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   display: block;
   margin: 1em 0;
   position: relative;
}
legend a::after {
   content: '';
   border: calc(var(--bordersize) / 2) solid yellow;
   position: absolute;
   right: calc(50% - calc(var(--bordersize) / 2));
   top: -1em;
   height: .4em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset >
   <legend align="center">Lorem<br>ipsum<a href="#">Learn more</a></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю и свой вариант)

```css
.demo {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px;
}

/* example */
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    border-left: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 48%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .container .content p:after,
  .container .content p:before,
  .container .content a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .container:before {
    height: 40px;
  }
  .container:after {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .container .content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -48%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .container .content p {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
  }
  .container .content p:after {
    height: 40px;
    left: 48%;
  }
  .container .content p:before {
    height: 40px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 48%;
  }
  .container .content a {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: yellow;
    display: block;
  }
  .container .content a,
  .container .content p {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .container .content a:after {
    top: calc(100% + 5px);
    height: 40px;
    left: 48%;
  }
  .container .content a:hover {
    color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Consumer Products Consulting</p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```